# Dotnet core- How to get selector string from IQueryable?

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core, iqueryable

IQueryable has extension method

```
IQueryable Select(this IQueryable source, string selector, params object[] values);
```

in `System.Linq.DynamicQueryable`
where can set query selector as string.

I need reverse method- **how can get this `string selector` from IQueryable?** `IQueryable.ToString()` doesnt work, because return "haotic" string.

Is it possible?

Comment: What is in IQueryable.Expression?

Comment: What is "haotic"? Basically, you can't - `DynamicQueryable` parses the string into an `Expression` tree and that tree no longer includes the original string.